# Double Valued Voltage in Rectifier with Capacitor Filter

Tags: diodes, filter, rectifier, bridge-rectifier, voltage-clipping

When a capacitor is charged in a full wave rectifier, as shown below, the load voltage closely follows the AC input voltage, less some 0.7V. When the input voltage falls from its peak, the voltage across the capacitor often falls less quickly. I'm confused as to how the voltage at the positive end of the capacitor can be different from the AC input voltage less some 0.7V when D2 is conducting. Wouldn't that imply a double-valued voltage at point a in the image? Where am I going wrong?

[image] Photo was taken from [Electric Shocks](https://electric-shocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Full-Bridge-Rectifier-Current-Flow-during-positive-Half-Cycle.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it can't be different when conducting (except for the 0.7V drop). But in the scenario you are asking, the diode is not conducting.

When AC waveform starts falling, diode stops conducting, as it won't be forward biased. Cap stays charged, or is slowly discharged to load. When AC waveform rises above the cap voltage again, the diode gets forwars biased and conducts current.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I think I get what's going on now.

Answer (score 1):

You have spotted that the supply current draw for a supply with a bridge rectifier and large smoothing capacitor is *discontinuous*.

For most of the time D2 *isn't* conducting, with just a short sharp period of capacitor recharging around the peak of the half cycle. This leads to high peak currents, poor power factor, and large amounts of harmonic generation.